# How to use react-admin's ChipField if there is no field/column name?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin, react-final-form

I have a `CheckboxGroupInput` field like this:

```
   <CheckboxGroupInput source="fruits" choices={[
        { 'name': 'apples' },
        { 'name': 'pears' }
    ]} optionValue='name'/>
```

which produces json likes this for the `fruits` field when the user selects both options:

```
  'fruits': ['apples','pears']
```

I want to display it in a `List` using `ChipField` which requires a `source` which I don't have, because the json is a plain string array.

source would be "name" if json looked like `fruits:[{'name':'apples'}, {'name':'pears'}]`

```
           <ArrayField source='fruits'>
                <SingleFieldList>
                    <ChipField source='???' />  
                </SingleFieldList>
            </ArrayField>
```

How can I show the contents of a plain string array with `ChipField` *OR* how do I tell `CheckboxGroupInput` to produce an object array instead of a string array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always a good idea to look at demo code. I managed to create a custom component called `SimpleChipField` by modifying a custom `ChipField` from the react-admin demo code. It shows the entire `record` as label.

```
import React from 'react';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    main: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        marginTop: -8,
        marginBottom: -8,
    },
    chip: { margin: 4 },
});

const SimpleChipField = ({ record }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return record ? (
        <span className={classes.main}>
            <Chip
                key={record}
                className={classes.chip}
                label={record}
            />
        </span>
    ) : null;
};

SimpleChipField.defaultProps = {
    addLabel: true,
};

export default SimpleChipField;
```

To use it, just put it instead of the regular `ChipField`.

```
    <ArrayField source="fruits">
        <SingleFieldList>
            <SimpleChipField />
        </SingleFieldList>
    </ArrayField>
```

Answer (score 6):

That's a great way to do it. I would offer an alternate option that doesn't require creating a new component and might be advantageous in different situations.

The FunctionField component can be really handy for these types of situations where you need to modify the data before it is displayed.

```jsx
<ArrayField source="fruits">
  <SingleFieldList>
    <FunctionField render={(record) => (
      <ChipField record={{name: record }} source="name" />
    )} />
  </SingleFieldList>
</ArrayField>
```

ChipField expects an object with property:value. You then specify the source as the property. With an ArrayField that only gives you the record as a single value you can use the FunctionField to turn that value into an object. Then the source is set to whatever property you use (in this example I used the generic "name")